# Not able to Trim or remove Hexadecimal character from SSRS report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report is throwing the below error when i run the report.

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
The server sent an unrecognizable response.
' ', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 16483664.

I found the issue from where it is causing.

Report parameter is having the special character which is causing this error.

I was tried many ways to trim or replace function to remove the special characters in report parameter.

=Replace(Join(Parameters!DimPCSite.Value,";" ),"","0x1A")
=Replace(Join(Parameters!DimPCPurchGroup.Value,";" ),"","0x1A

But i am getting another error.

error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The Value expression for the query parameter ‘’ contains an error: Conversion from type 'Object()' to type 'String' is not valid. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Please help me fix this issue by trim or remove the hexadecimal value from SSRS parameter.

Comment: You'll get more help if you share the expressions containing the error.

Comment: Have you checked your procs? Seems better to fix this on sql side than in SSRS.

Comment: @WesH i have edited my post and above is the expression which i am using.